# Min date with condition using window functions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I'm trying to use window functions to get the first date when ColC became True (grouped by id) and create a new column.

```
id         date           ColC
1        2017-04-20        t
1        2017-04-19        t
1        2017-04-18        t
2        2017-04-20        t
2        2017-04-19        f
```

So as the result I want to get the following:

```
id       first_date           
1        2017-04-18 
2        2017-04-20
```

So far I've got an idea of using either FIRST_VALUE(date) over(partition by id order by date) or min(). However, it's still a question how to incorporate the condition ColC = t.

Is it possible to get the result with one line?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm using BigQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and handles more generic cases when ColC can changes its status from f to t and back to f and then back to t again multiple times

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, DATE '2017-04-20' AS date, 't' AS ColC UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-04-19', 't' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-04-18', 't' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-04-21', 't' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-04-20', 't' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-04-19', 'f' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-04-18', 't' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-04-17', 'f' 
)
SELECT id, date AS switch_date
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id, date, ColC, 
    LAG(ColC) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS prevColC
  FROM yourTable
)
WHERE ColC = 't' AND IFNULL(prevColC, 'f') != 't'
-- ORDER BY id, date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to do:

```
select min(case when colc = 't' then date end) over (partition by id)
```

Of course, for your particular result, `group by` is simpler:

```
select id, min(date)
from t
where colc = 't'
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
select id, min(date) as first_date from tablename where ColC='t' group by id
```